# Why does the worst-case cost of Quick sort in Algorithms 4th edition not match my calculated cost?

Tags: algorithm, sorting

I'm reading the Algorithms 4th edition, and it tells me that Quick sort uses ~N^2/2 compares in the worst case since N+(N-1)+(N-2)+...+2+1=(N+1)N/2. However, the book also tells me that the cost of partitioning is always N+1. So I'm wondering  why the cost of worst case is  not (N+1)+(N-1+1)+(N-2+1)+...+(2+1)+0 = (N+1)+N+...+3=(N+4)(N-1)/2?

Comment: Does quicksort do anything beyond *compares*?

Comment: `(N+4)(N-1)/2` is `N^2 + 3N - 4`. When N is 1000, that's `1,002,996`: a difference of about .03%. As N increases, that percentage difference gets even smaller. When N is a million, the result--number of operations--is a little more than a trillion. A few million operations is a rounding error. Asymptotic analysis gives us an "order"--an estimate of the performance, not an exact number. Nobody's going to care if you're off by 0.0003% when you say "It'll take a trillion operation."

Comment: Yep, 100% to @JimMischel's comment.  The ~ says it's approximately equal to that value.  (N+4)(N-1)/2 = (N^2+3N-4)/2 = (N^2)/2 + 3N/2 - 2, which as N gets larger, the 3N/2 - 2 part becomes a vanishingly small part of the total value, leaving the value approximately equal to N^2/2.

Comment: partitioning is `N-1` comparisons

Answer (score 2):

They goofed? Quicksort partition needs to compare the pivot to each other element, which is exactly N−1 comparisons. In the worst case, the pivot is either the min or the max element each time, so the total number of comparisons is (N−1) + (N−2) + … + 1 + 0 = N(N−1)/2, which is all pairs.

Comment: Worth noting that their conclusion is still right (it is still approximately N^2/2 comparisons for any larger values of N), even if they goofed the math a little.